# Tkinter button image looks ugly on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently developing a tkinter GUI and i have trouble with the tkinter button image quality.

When i run the code on Linux ubuntu 18.04 the images are very nice whereas when i run them on windows 10 there are way uglier.

To be sure, i checked the problem on the same screen and it turned out it wasn't the cause of the problem.

Here is how i coded my image buttons:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file = "pictures/ball.png")
resized_photo=photo.subsample(x=int(screen_width / (167 * scale_factor_square)),
                                                    y=int(screen_width / (167 * scale_factor_square)))

New_Championship_button = Button(
            fenetre_accueil, bg='black', image=resized_photo, activebackground="white", bd=0, highlightthickness = 0, command=lambda: create_new_championship())
    New_Championship_button.configure(height=int(screen_height/28*1.77), width=int(screen_width/28))
```

Here are the two pictures:

On Windows:

[image: image on Windows 10]

On Linux:

[image: image on Linux]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `When i run the code on Linux ubuntu 18.04 the images are very nice whereas when i run them on windows 10 there are way uglier.` – please show us some images

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: Maybe `subsample()` does not use the same algorithm in Linux and Windows or you are using different versions of tcl/tk. You could try to resize your pictures with a different library, e.g. [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize).